# Make div clickable, but don't break embedded links (multiple divs on one page)

Tags: html

I need to make a div clickable which per HTML5 is easy enough:

```
<a href='#'>
  <div>Hello World</div>
</a>
```

The problem I am having is some of my div objects contain links:

```
<div>Hello World. <a href='#'>Click me</a>
```

So the method in the first example breaks whenever I have an embedded link.

```
<a href='#'>
  <div>Hello World  <a href='#'>Click me</a></div>
</a>
^^^^ already closed here ---------------^^^^
```

**edit:**  Also, there are multiple divs on one page. Each div points to a different URL.

Is there a better, clean way of handling this, so that empty space in the div is clickable, except for text - which could be plaintext or a link, like in my second example.

Comment: What should happen on clicking the `div`?

Comment: Don't wrap the div in an anchor and use a javascript click even to handle when div's are clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of wrapping your `div`s in a link, add an eventlistener to the `div`s which checks if a link was the event target:

```js
// get a NodeList of all divs with the attribute data-url
// and destructure the NodeList to an Array using [...NodeList]
const divs = [...document.querySelectorAll('div[data-url]')];

// now that divs is an array we can use Array methods to iterate
for (const div of divs) {
  div.addEventListener('click', event => {
    switch (event.target.tagName) {
      case 'A':
        // do nothing
        break;
      default:
        // do whatever you want to do on div click here
        console.log(event.target.dataset.url);
        // this would be
        // location.href = event.target.dataset.url;
        // in your application
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div data-url="https://connexo.de/defuse">Hello World  <a href='#'>Click me</a></div>
<div data-url="http://example.com">Hello World  <a href='#'>Click me</a></div>
```

Please note that my code example is based on ES6 syntax. If you need to support browsers that don't understand ES6, you either need a transpiler like Babel, or you need to re-write that code to ES5. Here's the same example in ES5:

```js
// get a NodeList of all divs with the attribute data-url
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-url]');

// now use Array.prototype.forEach on the 
// NodeList using Function.prototype.call()
Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function(div) {
  div.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    switch (event.target.tagName) {
      case 'A':
        // do nothing
        break;
      default:
        // do whatever you want to do on div click here
        console.log(event.target.dataset.url);
        // this would be
        // location.href = event.target.dataset.url;
        // in your application
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<div data-url="https://connexo.de/defuse">Hello World  <a href='#'>Click me</a></div>
<div data-url="http://example.com">Hello World  <a href='#'>Click me</a></div>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have multiple clickable divs on the same document, each pointing to a different url.

Comment: Ok modified yours as follows.  I now have multiple clickable divs on one page, each pointing to its own URL.  https://jsfiddle.net/tx6duywk/1/

Comment: ok actually this *kind of* works, but clicking on one of the embedded links causes the parent window to go to the desired link, but then it also opens a new tab/window with the same embedded link.

Comment: You can always opt to cancel the default action of the event using `event.preventDefault();`. You haven't described what is supposed to happen when clicking the link. Maybe it would help if you described what you need, not how you tried to solve it.

Comment: Right, lost in my details.   I have a grid of addresses as cards on a page.  User can click the card and be taken to an edit page, or they can click embedded links in each card to go to additional views (not the main edit page).   I backed out the changes in the fiddle above and have something like this for now:  https://jsfiddle.net/gqptran3/

Comment: Don't use inline event handlers.

Comment: Ok, is there an alternative?

Comment: Use  `Element.prototype.addEventlistener()` just as I did in my answer.

Comment: If I have two divs on the same page, and only one `addEventlistener()`, how do I specify a different URL for each div?

Comment: Put it on each `div` into a `data-url`-attribute. In your event listener, read the attribute as `event.target.dataset.url` and do a `location.href` to it. Let me edit my answer's code.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the container to act as a link as well as to contain another links, you can solve that with CSS.

```
<style>
    .container { position: relative; }
    .back-layer { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; }
    .container p { position: relative; z-index: 1; }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <a class="back-layer" href="http://example.com"></a>
    <p>I am text with <a href="http://example.com">link.</a></p>
    <p>I am another paragraph with <a href="http://example.com">link</a>.</p>
</div>
```

`.back-layer` is "stretched" across relatively positioned `.container`. `p`s are assigned `z-index: 1` to be placed on top of the `.back-layer`.

This approach does not need any javascript and might work better for you semantically, if your links are true links.

Comment: @connexo: There is no link inside link, `.back-layer` is stretched visually only. Paragraphs inside `.container` have `z-index` so they appear on top of the `.back-layer` - as I've explained in my answer.